# Heatmap with multiple names for each row

Tags: r, row, heatmap, names

I am trying to construct a heatmap like the following picture that each row has multiple names or information related to it (like in this case product, name and number).
does anyone know what package in R can make a heatmap like this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i80XX.jpg)

Comment: I've done similar things using a combination of `ggplot` and `patchwork`.

Comment: Isn't it a simple table with few colored columns? Like `kable` examples: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html